# Get oldest timestamp from each user_id

Tags: mysql

Database of "sales"

Each "sold_by" is the person who essentially has made that particular sale. My aim is to get the most recent "sale_date" grouped by "sold_by" to return one record for each unique "sold_by" record (which is stored as an integer in my database, but this is an example)

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦══════════════════╗
║ sale_id ║ sold_by ║    sale_date     ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬══════════════════╣
║       0 ║ PETER   ║ 01/01/2017 00:00 ║
║       1 ║ JOHN    ║ 01/01/2017 00:00 ║
║       2 ║ PETER   ║ 30/03/2017 00:00 ║
║       3 ║ JOHN    ║ 03/02/2017 00:00 ║
║       4 ║ SIMON   ║ 04/02/2017 00:00 ║
║       5 ║ JOHN    ║ 05/01/2017 00:00 ║
║       6 ║ SIMON   ║ 26/01/2017 00:00 ║
║       7 ║ PETER   ║ 07/01/2017 00:00 ║
║       8 ║ SIMON   ║ 28/01/2017 00:00 ║
║       9 ║ JOHN    ║ 09/01/2017 00:00 ║
║       0 ║ PETER   ║ 20/01/2017 00:00 ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩══════════════════╝
```

Database example for account_manager_sellers (please note, the ID matches `sold_by` in the table above.

```
╔════╦══════════════╗
║ id ║ company_name ║
╠════╬══════════════╣
║  0 ║ PETER        ║
║  1 ║ JOHN         ║
║  2 ║ SIMON        ║
╚════╩══════════════╝
```

The example below works but is not working as desired, it is not getting MIN or MAX date but seemingly returning a random date from the middle of the database.

```
SELECT `sold_by`, `sale_date`
FROM   `sales`
  NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT   `sold_by`, MAX(`sale_date`) AS entry_date
    FROM     `sales`
    GROUP BY `sold_by`
  ) AS tmin
  JOIN `account_manager_sellers` USING (`id`)
  WHERE `sale_date` < '2017-03-31 00:00:00';
```

So ultimately, I need to get ONE record for each unique `sold_by` but it needs to be the most recent date. So from the first table above it would return:

```
+---+-------+------------------+
| 2 | PETER | 30/03/2017 00:00 | 
+---+-------+------------------+
| 3 | JOHN  | 03/02/2017 00:00 | 
+---+-------+------------------+
| 4 | SIMON | 04/02/2017 00:00 |
+---+-------+------------------+
```

P.S I also tried removing the MAX(`sale_date`) from the sub query, and replacing that with an ORDER BY `sale_date` LIMIT 1 (but obviously it only returned one sole result)

Comment: Please post the definitions of both tables.

Comment: Also, the columns in your sample table do not seem to match up with the names used in the query below it.

Comment: Apologies, I had renamed them to make it more understandable but failed to replace some of the references, will do that now. - Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic query you want might look something like this:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM plans p1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT seller_id, MAX(plan_written) AS entry_date
    FROM plans
    GROUP BY seller_id
) p2
    ON p1.seller_id = p2.seller_id AND
       p1.plan_written = p2.entry_date;
```

You also have another join to the `account_manager_sellers` table, but since I can't see your table definitions, don't know your columns, etc., I won't attempt an answer for that.

You might want to move away from using natural joins, because they can obfuscate the join conditions in your query.

Comment: Just got round to testing this, didn't need to do anything apart from add a WHERE clause, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Hi Tim, for some reason, it works for some but not for others, I tested a few records, and it is not always getting the record with the MAX(date)

Comment: @PeterBennett _Edit_ your question, and show sample data for all tables involved, and the desired output.  Make sure that the column names in your sample match exactly the columns in the actual tables.